# Some Hyperlinks not opening with Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, pandas, hyperlink, openpyxl

I have a few hundred files with data and hyperlinks in them that I was trying to upload and append to a single DataFrame when I realized that Pandas was not reading any of the hyperlinks.

I then tried to use Openpyxl to read the hyperlinks in the input Excel files and write a new column into the excels with the text of the hyperlink that hopefully Pandas can read into my dataframe.

However, I am running into issues with my testing the openpyxl code. It is able to read and write some of the hyperlinks but not the others.

My sample file has three rows and looks like this:

[image: Input data]

My actual data has hyperlinks in the way that I have it for "Google" in my test data set.

[image: Hyperlink style 1]

The other two hyperlinks in my text data, I inserted by right clicking on the cell and pasting the link.

[image: Second type of hyperlink input]

Sample Test file here: [Text.xlsx](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_A41-8k0JxtS38P3bO_QE0naHCgufTVV/view?usp=sharing)

Here is the code I wrote to read the hyperlink and paste it in a new column. It works for the first two rows (India and China) but fails for the third row (Google). It's unfortunate because all of my actual data is of that type. Can someone please help me figure it out?

```
import openpyxl 

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

column_indices = [1]
max_col = ws.max_column

ws.cell(row=1,column = max_col+1).value = "Hyperlink Text"
for row in range(2,ws.max_row+1): 
    for col in column_indices:
        print(ws.cell(row, column=1).hyperlink.target)
        ws.cell(column=max_col+1,row=row).value = ws.cell(row, column=1).hyperlink.target


wb.save('test.xlsx')
```

[image]

Comment: What do you want to do if it's not a hyperlink, skip ??

Comment: @Sushanth umm.. In my actual data, the columns should have hyperlinks but if it doesn't then I wanna catch whatever value it has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cells where you are using the HYPERLINK function (like google.com) will not be of type hyperlink.   You will need to process the cells with HyperLink function using re so similar function.
The values looks like below,

```
>>> ws.cell(2,1).value
'China'
>>> ws.cell(3,1).value
'India'
>>> ws.cell(4,1).value
'=HYPERLINK("www.google.com","google")'
```

Suggested code to handle HYPERLINK :

```
val = ws.cell(row,column).value
if val.find("=HYPERLINK") >= 0 :
    hyplink = ws.cell(4,1).value  # Or use re module for more robust check
```

Note :  The second for loop to iterate over columns seems not required since you are always using column=1.

Comment: How can I extract just the hyperlink? I don't want "=HYPERLINK("www.google.com",...)" but just "www.google.com"... ah you said regular expressions in a subsequent step.got it. Thanks

Comment: Crude way of doing it would be -`val.split("\"")[1]` .   Better way to do it would be using the `re` module with the right regexp like `re.findall('=HYPERLINK\(\"(.*?)\"', val` .   You might need to update the regular expression as needed by your different Hyperlink patterns